# Append List values using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using JQuery append how to push list values to another div section on button click

For example:

I have two list values

```
1.Adam  

2.Lance
```

if i click on add button the Adam value should be added to another div section same for lance.. etc

https://jsfiddle.net/oa2hfLum/3/

help me out in achieving it Thanks!

**html**

```
<div>
<ol id="sortable">

</ol>
</div>

<div>
        <ul id="draggable">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <label class='lbl'>
                        Lance
                    </label>
                    <button>Add To Top container</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <label class='lbl'>
                        Adam
                    </label>
                    <button>Add To Top container</button>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#sortable").append('<li></li>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `label` text using [**`.prev()`**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [**`.text()`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var label = $(this).prev().text();
    $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/qx69o1bd/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#sortable").append('<li>'+$(this).prev('label').text()+'</li>');
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oa2hfLum/4/

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and for solving my issue Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#sortable").append('<li></li>');
```

to

```
$("#sortable").append('<li>'+$(this).parent().find('label').html()+'</li>');
```